# Google Cloud SQL - Old backup older than 7 days

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Cloud SQL retains up to 7 automated backups for each instance.

Is it possible to restore backup after 7 days?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is "No" as per the documentation. Either take on-demand backups and delete them at your desired retention, or export data to flat file. 
[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups)

Answer (score 0):

actually, it is possible if you do an on-demand backup. that one will not be removed.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backing-up#gcloud_7

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33106935)